how to get "below header" row to display as 1 column instead of 3?
I have a WP site and the "Below Header" row consists of 3 columns.  But I'm trying to make that row display as a single column so the button that I put in the middle will display full width.  I'm guessing that this is possible, since it seems like this would be a fairly common use case, but I don't see a way off hand, and ChatGPT doesn't seem to provide clear guidance on a path forward for this.  Can you provide some insight on how to achieve this?

